# Algorithm for finding the maximum number of vertices you can visit, given a start point and a maximum distance you can travel

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have an undirected graph with positive edge weights. I am given a start point and the maximum amount of distance I can travel, and in the end, I must return to the start point. What sort of algorithm can do this for me, and give me the path that results?

I understand java well, so if you can, please make code samples look similar to java.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but doesn't it sound like the Traveling Salesman Problem with a constraint on the distance traveled? Please feel free to correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: I believe this is problem is simpler than the "Traveling Salesman Problem" , this problem just want to know the maximum number of vertices you can pass, a DFS will do the job.

Comment: The problem is ambiguous at the moment. Can the path go through the same vertex twice? If a path goes A->B->A->B->A, how many vertexes are visited: 2 or 5?

Comment: If it's forbidden to visit any vertex more than once, then this problem is NP-hard, since you could easily use it to solve the NP-hard Hamiltonian Path problem in polynomial time: Just pick a distance safely larger than the distance of any path (for example, sum up *all* the edge weights), and then solve your problem with this distance.  If the answer to your problem is that all nodes can be visited, then there is a HP, otherwise there isn't.

Comment: The path going through A-B-A-B-A travels through 2 vertices, and you can visit vertices more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said a DFS should do the trick, this sample code gives the idea. **But beware, this sample code don't handle cyclic reference**, you will have to do that

```
public class Answer {

    private static final int MAX_WEIGHT = 11;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node node1 = new Node("node 1");
        Node node1_1 = new Node("node 1-1");
        Node node1_1_1 = new Node("node 1-1-1");
        Node node1_2 = new Node("node 1-2");
        Node node1_2_1 = new Node("node 1-2-1");
        Node node1_2_1_1 = new Node("node 1-2-1-1");

        node1.addNeighbour(node1_1, 1);
        node1_1.addNeighbour(node1_1_1, 2);

        node1.addNeighbour(node1_2, 1);
        node1_2.addNeighbour(node1_2_1, 2);
        node1_2_1.addNeighbour(node1_2_1_1, 3);

        System.out.println("max of nodes  = " + travel(node1, 0));

    }

    private static int travel(Node node, int totalWeight) {
        int maxNodes = 1;

        for (Map.Entry<Node, Integer> entry : node.neighbours.entrySet()) {
            Integer weight = entry.getValue();

            int nodes = 1;
            if ((totalWeight + weight) * 2 <= MAX_WEIGHT) {
                nodes += travel(entry.getKey(), totalWeight + weight);
            }

            if (nodes > maxNodes) {
                maxNodes = nodes;
            }
        }

        return maxNodes;
    }

}

class Node {

    String id;
    Map<Node, Integer> neighbours;

    public Node(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        neighbours = new HashMap<Node, Integer>();
    }

    public void addNeighbour(Node node, int weight) {
        neighbours.put(node, weight);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Node{");
        sb.append("id='").append(id).append('\'');
        sb.append(", neighbours=").append(neighbours);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now realise this is still NP-hard, even if vertices can be visited more than once: [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is NP-hard even on unweighted graphs, so we are free to create an instance of your problem using arbitrarily chosen weights.  Specifically, given an instance (G = (V, E), k) of Hamiltonian Path, we can create an instance (G' = (V', E'), w, s, d) of your problem in which:

- V' = V, plus a new vertex, s
- E' = E, plus the edge (s, u) for every vertex u in V
- The weight w(e) of every edge e in E' is 1
- The starting point is s
- The maximum total travel distance is |V|+1.

If the solution to this instance is |V|+1 distinct vertices, then clearly it contains every vertex in G' exactly once, so removing the vertex s from the cycle will leave a path through all the remaining vertices, i.e., a Hamiltonian path in the original graph G.  If the solution to this instance is less than |V|+1, then no Hamiltonian path exists in G -- since if one did, we would indeed have gotten a solution of |V|+1.

So, if your problem could be solved in polynomial time, then so could an NP-complete problem.  That means that it's very unlikely that your problem can be solved in polynomial time.